# RedLaser iOS SDK returns nan for barcodeLocation in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, barcode-scanner, ios8.1, nsvalue

I am using `RedLaser` `iOS` `SDK` for my app. I used `barcodeLocation` property to identify if the `barcode` lies inside my active region frame. In `iOS 8.1`,that property returns nan. Hence I could not do the precise level of scanning.  Is there any alternative way to find the `barcode` location. Thanks